# How do I avoid having duplicate of plugin in trunk?

Tags: plugins, svn

I published a plugin and then installed it into a test site to check it was published OK.

The copy that was installed contains:

- plugin.php
- readme.txt
- trunk/plugin.php
- trunk/readme.txt

The trunk folder is redundant and other plugins don't seem to come duplicated.  How can I avoid the plugin files getting downloaded twice?

Comment: What does `trunk` of SVN looks like?

Comment: Are you new to using SVN? I know i had issues sorting out the folder and file structure when i started out. Totally confusing when you're starting out.. (well it was for me, i can't speak for you obviously)...

Comment: @Rarst trunk looks like in question.  Nice idea, though.  I had hoped that I'd copied trunk into itself but no such luck.

Comment: @Rarst in fact you are right.  I had trunk duplicated in the tags folder.  Mystery over.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know which OS and/or software you use but regarding SVN it's quite simple :

```
$ svn co http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/your-plugin-name
```

Then you just have to add your files in trunk and/or maybe in assets (banner,screenshots).
Then :

```
$ svn add trunk/*
```

and or :

```
$ svn add assets/*
```

Last step is :

```
$ svn ci -m "initial upload"
```

That's pretty much what I use to release plugins on wordpress.org, hope this will help :)

Comment: @TwwetPressFr Thanks.  I did that.  At least I think I did.  I guess I did something wrong though, because the trunk folder gets duplicated.